# Azure MVC 5 muy lento al cargar

Tags: mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, azure

amigos hice una aplicación en MVC5 y la despliegue en Azure con APP SERVICES, hasta ahí todo bien, el problema es que cada cierto tiempo cuando deseo ingresar a la página, la primera vez la carga se hace muy lenta, más o menos unos 30 segundos, ya después si funciona correctamente, pero como hago para evitar que eso suceda, creo que el servidor entra como en estado de suspensión cada 30 minutos y por eso ocurre eso, quisiera saber cómo evitar esa primera carga lenta después de 30 minutos de inactividad, gracias

Comment: Has activado la opción Siempre Activo dentro de Configuración > Configuración General ?

Comment: Gracias amigo, era eso, jeje

Answer (score 0):

Activar dentro de Configuración > Configuración General la opción Siempre Activo.